# Where to get Socket.io/Websocket server details

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a socket.io server. According to the socket.io documentation ([version  compatibility](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#version-compatibility)),"the client and the server must use compatible versions for everything to work", else we get an error like this one [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/586).Problem is, I dont know where to look for server's Engine.io/java/python protocol version on an open webpage [Demo.tv](https://demo.betgames.tv/). I can run `pip freeze` to get my socketio and engineio version, but I dont know if I have a webpage open, where do I get protocol versions of the server. [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW8nL.png)